# Using two different Versions of jQuery in Angular 4 Project results in conflict (ngrx & visual sedimentation)

Tags: jquery, angular, d3.js, redux, ngrx

Our project consists of:

- Angular 4 components
- Redux Store State management to save states client side (ngrx)
- socket.io for events and database

We are trying to include the [Visual Sedimentation](http://www.visualsedimentation.org/) library for a live visualization of certain events (but the live vis of events is not the problem right now, just showing the example code in my home component). This lib uses a pretty old jQuery version and d3 version 2. On an test angluar project we already succeeded in including this library.

Here is a [repository link](https://github.com/magdastone/TestProject_VS) from the test project.

But trying to include, and show it in an component in our actual project wasn't possible because redux already uses another (way newer) version of jQuery. This is the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JycrL.png) I get in my console.

This is how we tried to include it: in [home.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F26U3.png) we placed the Bar Chart into my home component with `<h1 id="myDemo">Bar Chart</h1>`

In [home.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD6d5.png) we declared the $ variable and then a mySettings const [down there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igKpa.png) we created the

```
const barChart = $('#myDemo').vs(mySettings).data('visualSedimentation');
```

the min.js file we need for this barchart is included in scripts in angular.cli.json, the min.js file is placed in the assets folder.
jquery was installed (npm install --save jquery)
types was installed (npm install @types/jquery)

I can't find any example code that includes the same modules as we do.

Comment: Readers would be well advised **to be very careful when downloading whole projects from Dropbox**. Remember that running `npm install` on untrusted and unchecked code can result in malicious actions being run under your user account (key loggers, file stealing, file deletion, etc).

Comment: Lena, we discourage file locker links here, and not just for security reasons. I would suggest you try to add the _relevant_ code to your question, since if the Dropbox link is essential, then if it is deleted in future, the question may not make any sense to future readers, and would have to be closed and deleted. Thus, we ask that questions are written in a (mostly) self-contained fashion here.

Comment: oh sorry. I didn't think about that. one moment.

Comment: (Thanks, ping me when it's updated please at `@halfer`. Note it is best to reproduce the files that people actually need, rather than the whole lot. I think it is OK to keep the file locker link at the end, since it then optional rather than necessary).

Comment: updated it @halfer

Comment: That is, unfortunately, still an external link, and will be considered brittle for the purposes of presenting a question here for future readers. For the benefit of keeping the question **here on the site**, please use a formatted code block. In general you should not need to present more than two or three files - if you need to present the whole project, it may be too broad for this platform.

Comment: I'm sorry. now i get it. I will put up code blocks. I will inform you.

Answer (score 1):

Took a look on your demo project. In file vs.0.1-min.js you can see last line:

```
if(typeof(P)!=undefined){return P}}}})(jQuery);
```

It means window.jQuery variable is a param for this lib (which variable will be used as jquery).

So you need:

1. Put jquery.min.js of version you need for vs lib in assets .
2. Import jquery version you need for vs libe to another variable:
   in index.html

   ```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
       window.$j = jQuery.noConflict();
       // $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.
   </script>
   <script src="vs.0.1-min.js"></script>
   <!--Here the main bundle-->
   ```

   3. Then change last line in vs.0.1-min.js (in index.html your project js file should be before vs.0.1-min.js script tag)

   `if(typeof(P)!=undefined){return P}}}})($j);`

Sorry, don't  have time now to finish it till the end, but idea is clear, try.

Comment: but where exactly would you place these script tags? i can't just include scripts in my home.component.html and i never ever tried to include a script in the index.html of an angular project. could you please further describe it? i get your idea, the actions of the two different jquery files should be seperated. but the jquery that ngrx uses is in a node_module, and the function of ngrx has to work all the time because it is our client side logic.

Comment: I need to see the project files then. And anyway  some trying and debugging is needed. I don't think it is possible to provide 100% working code not even seeing the project files an not playing with the problem.

Comment: is there any possibility that I can send you the project without putting it up here on stack overflow for everyone to see? I am planning to put up the necessary code blocks afterwards, when it works. But I can't (I am not allowed) to put the code up publicly.

Comment: My Skype is kievsash@ukr.net but don't have time these days..Maybe after 8th of January?